# CS0051 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'CharityDbContext' is less accessible than method 'Campaign.Campaign(CharityDbContext)'

Tags: c#

I am working my through an example of MVC to teach myself. I have the above error message when I am creating a constructor

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebApplication5.Models;    
    
namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class Campaign : Controller
    {
        private readonly CharityDbContext _db;
    
        public Campaign(CharityDbContext db) -- error occurs here
        {
            _db = db;
        }
    
        public IActionResult Details()
        {
            //IEnumerable<Campaign> objList = _db.CampaignName;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can see CharityDbContext is public in my CharityContext.cs

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
    
#nullable disable
    
namespace WebApplication5.Models
{
    public partial class CharityContext : DbContext
    {
        public CharityContext()
        {
        }
    
        public CharityContext(DbContextOptions<CharityContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the private read only - to public read only but this has made no difference.

Could anyone advise what I am missing please?

Comment: Please show the definition of `CharityDbContext` type as well. I assume that was what you intended in the second code piece of your question, but you've shown `CharityContext`, not `CharityDbContext`, perhaps you're using the wrong type in the first code piece?

Comment: `CharityContext` or `CharityDbContext` ?

Comment: `CharityDbContext`  class must be declared as public: `public class CharityDbContext ...` to be used in the `public Campaign(...)` constructor

Comment: I think the issue is around type as pointed out by Lasse, I am going to revisit it now I have had a break, Thanks for the replies everyone